# $|\vec{a}|=4,|\vec{b}|=2|\vec{c}|,(\vec{a}-\vec{c})\cdot (\vec{b}-\vec{c})=3$, try minimize $|\vec{a}-\vec{b}|$

Tags: geometry, inequality, vectors, maxima-minima

$\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are vectors on a plane, which satisfy

$$
|\vec{a}|=4,|\vec{b}|=2|\vec{c}|
$$

and the equation

$$
(\vec{a}-\vec{c})\cdot (\vec{b}-\vec{c})=3
$$

**Find** the minimum value of $|\vec{a}-\vec{b}|$.

I've checked the reference solution of this problem, which notes

$$
\vec a=\vec{OA},\vec{b}=\vec{OB},c=\vec{OC}
$$

then notes

$$
\vec{OM}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{OA}+\vec{OB})
$$

so we can translate the equation $(\vec{a}-\vec{c})\cdot (\vec{b}-\vec{c})=3$ into

$$
|\vec{CM}|^2-\frac{1}{4}|\vec{a}-\vec{b}|^2=3
$$

(It's better to draw a picture there to show the geometric motivation, but my technique is limited. I'm sorry...)

So $|\vec{a}-\vec{b}|$ get the minimum value iff $|\vec{CM}|$ get the minimum value.

**But** the next step just assumes $O,C,M$ were on the same line. It really confuses me, because this step is naive only if C was free to move on the whole circle determined by the half length of $\vec{b}$. However, if $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ was determined, the $\vec{c}$ was also determined, instead of being wherever of a circle. I've tried another order to determine the variables but it didn't work. I'm seeking for your assitance, or you can just show another solution all by yourself.

**EDIT.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point $C$ lies on the circle of centre $O$ and radius ${1\over2}|\vec b|$, and also on the circle of centre $M$ and radius $\sqrt{3+{1\over4}|\vec b-\vec a|^2}$. If $B$ is too close to $A$ then those circles don't intersect and $C$ doesn't exist. The limiting case is when the circles are tangent, hence to find the minimum of $|\vec b-\vec a|$ we can consider only those positions of $B$ such that the circles are tangent, their tangency point being $C$. But in this case $C$ lies between the centres of the circles, i.e. points $OCM$ are aligned.

EDIT.

If we set $AM=r$ (i.e. $AB=2r$), $\angle OAM=\theta$, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
OB^2 &=4r^2+16-16r\cos\theta\\
OM^2 &=r^2+16-8r\cos\theta\\
MC^2 &=r^2+3
\end{align}
$$
and the condition of tangency is
$$
{1\over2}OB+MC=OM.
$$
This can be conveniently solved for $\cos\theta$:
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{3-3 r^2\pm2 \sqrt{3 r^4+7 r^2-6}}{4 r}
$$
and the minimum value of $r$ giving a real result is that which makes the square root to vanish, namely:
$$
r=\sqrt{2\over3},
$$
corresponding to:
$$
\cos\theta=\sqrt{3\over32}.
$$

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've tried this direction, but therein lies the rub. I have no idea about whether the step to shorten the |AB| would have an affect on other variables, and my previous idea was to stablize the angle between OA and AB then shorten the |AB|, however, if the angle was acute, the length of OB may firstly decrease until OB was perpendicular to AB and then increase, so I can't keep the monotonicity. Now my idea is to stablelize the length of OB and then move A. This works a bit better because A lies on a circle of center O and radius 4, (Uh, characters left were not enough now...)

Comment: I have a futher try about my idea written above, and I've constructed an example that 
two circles won't get separated in the limit situation that the angle between OB and OA was 0, of course, this is the minimum situation. (If we stabilize the length of OB and see which A would lead to the minimum length of AB, of course, it's equal to minimize the angle between OB and OA.) If the conclusion that tangency leads to the minimum length is true, we must strictly exclude the cases I mentioned.

Comment: I don't understand which anomalous cases you are talking about, could you show a sketch? For $B=A$ those two circles don't intersect and point $C$ doesn't exist. If you now move $B$ away from $A$ at a certain angle $\theta$, then the shortest length $AB$ for which point $C$ exists corresponds to the tangency of the two circles. I don't see how this couldn't hold true.

Comment: I guess the "B=A" case indicate you just let $|AB|$ **increase from zero**, and once we have intersections, the |AB| we set now is the minimum. It's true that, at least intuitively, the number of intersections won't jump from 0 to 2 since our transformation is "continuous". In my previous idea, I just want to stabilize some variables and get the minimum case under the stabilization, since dealing with too many variables is hard. I exclude the possibility of this method, because movements of center and radius happen on the different object. However, the "continuity" allow us to simplify...